# unit testing in MVC3

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on MVC3 front end. We have an Infrastructure project which is a bridge between UI and Web Service. But Infrastructure is not ready yet. I have views, view models, controllers as below. I have to do unit testing. I have to pass my view model to the infrastructure, so that it will do add, save functionality. From where do I pass the viewmodel to the infrastructure? Is it in controller? If so how? Please provide me a class which will do unit test for the given view, viewmodel, controller. I was asked to mock my view model as the infrastructure and web service are not ready yet so that I can do some testing.

ViewModel

```
    public class BuildRegionModel : IBuildRegionModel
    {
    #region Constructor / Desctructor
    public BuildRegionModel()
    {
        Name = "User123";
        Description = "Long text";
        ModifyUser = new User();
        ModifyUser.FirstName = "First Name";
        StatusSelected = new Status();
        ModifyDate = DateTime.Today;
        StatusLists = new List<ICode>();
        StatusLists.Add(new Status("A","Active"));
        StatusLists.Add(new Status("I", "InActive"));
    }

    ~BuildRegionModel()
    {
        StatusLists = null;
        StatusSelected = null;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<ICode> StatusLists { get; set; }
    public ICode StatusSelected { get; set; }
    public IUser ModifyUser { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifyDate { get; set; }        
    #endregion
}
```

Controller

```
public class BuildRegionController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(BuildRegionModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(BuildRegionModel model, string button)
    {

        if (button == "Add")
            {

            }
        if (button == "Save")
            {

            }
        if (button == "Cancel")
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        return View(model);
    }

}
```

I am looking for a test class in this scenario so that I can continue with others.

Comment: If you're asking how to create a mock so you can continue working, you simply need to make a mock object with a signature you are expecting and then inject that mock into your controller. Am I understanding your question correctly?

Comment: I mocked my viewmodels so that I can see some data in the views and inject them in to the controller. I am not able to figure out what tests do I have to do and how.

Comment: What you created is a stub, not a mock. Mocks are used to test behavior (e.g. "did the code call 'Save' on my mock at least once?").

Comment: No I dint create a mock yet. where and how do I create it? I didn't write any test code yet. how do I create a mock and write the test code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your model is really a ViewModel (or in your given context I tend to call them EditModel) you shouldn't pass those on to another layer (not sure what your definition of infrastructure is here).

I sometimes have my controller pass the real business layer object to my EditModel and let the EditModel update the business object. I do this bidirectional, the EditModel will project or pull data from the real model before being send to a view.

I do this to keep my controller methods short and avoid having a lot of left-right mapping code in them.

Any behavior (complexer them simple mutations) or service calls I do keep in my controller (e.g. Save or Add calls against some repository).

What you could unit test is:

- Does the ViewModel correctly mutate the (infrastructure? or business) model?
- Given the button parameters value is the controller calling the appropriate method on the Infrastructure (you need to define an interface for the infrastructure and mock it).
- Does the controller return the correct ActionResult with the correct model data?
- Does the controller return the correct ActionResult when the ViewModel doesn't validate or when the (infrastructure? or business) model refuses a change.

Have you considered creating a Save, Add and Cancel method on your controller? It would help both testability and readability if you don't funnel everything through the 'Index' method.